# Does private browsing prevent socket events?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, sockets

I usually do my work in Google Chrome (v36.0.1985.143), private browsing enabled. I use Firefox to browse Stack Exchange, in normal mode so that all my logins are persisted.

Sometimes I accidentally open an SE question in Chrome, so I copy-paste the URL to Firefox and get on reading. I left the SE tab in Chrome open, and up-voted a question in Firefox.

Normally, you immediately see other users' voting activity via socket event emitting (possibly [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), I don't know SE's back-end). I noticed that in my Chrome tab, I didn't see the upvote that I had cast in Firefox. I had to refresh to be able to see the vote count change.

So, as the title of the question states: *does private browsing prevent socket events?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to check this is using the Chrome Web Developer tools(<kbd>F12</kbd>) to look at the connections.  Here's a screenshot  I took from an incognito window:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the connection to `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` has the response `101 Switching Port`, which is the response that gets returned when a [Web Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) connections is negotiated.

Comment: I see that now, thanks! Will the request ever come through? It seems to be 'pending' forever. I just did the same in Chrome non-private browsing, and no socket emission. Is it just a Chrome thing?

Comment: It should "just work," as you can see its working for me.  Are you behind an HTTP proxy or anything that might be disrupting the connection?

Comment: Well, I'm hard-wired into a university connection, so imagine there are a lot of tunnels to go through to get to the outside, including a proxy or two :P

Comment: Yeah, many proxies don't play nicely with Web Sockets since its more than normal HTTP traffic.

Comment: That would explain why it can't switch ports. Interesting... well that was kind of a let-down! I was hoping that I stumbled upon something a bit more interesting than *because my univeristy said so* =/